# How to set landing page in a codeigniter project setup?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I'm doing a project with codeigniter and I have a requirement to make a landing page from where user has option for entering the main site. I have already set the front controller for main site visit. Now how to make this front controller calling possible after the landing page?

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'front';
```

Comment: Change the default controller to a new landing page controller?

Answer (score 1):

You Just Create a new Controller name as Landing_page and you have to set this as your default controller `$route['default_controller'] = 'Landing_page';`  i think you were create the landing page is in codeigniter itself as a view page, if so u just load the view (landing) page in index() function of the same, otherwise you have to redirect the url to the subdomain as follows

**Landing page as view:**

```
Class Landing_page extends CI_Controller{

     function index(){

      $this->load->view('landing_page');

     }
}
```

**As sub Domain:**

```
Class Landing_page extends CI_Controller{

     function index(){

     redirect('http://landingPage.Your_website.com');

     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but my website is store specific and from the landing page i have to navigate to that selected store. Here the code base is same for all site but the site url is different as subdomain. Once a store is selected from the next time that landing page will not come out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create one controller in `project_folder/application/controller/Front.php`

```
Class Front extends CI_Controller{

     function index(){
          echo "Welcome to Front Page";
     }
}
```

All ready in route.php you have mentioned fonrt controller is default page.